# Is there a way to split a number into parts by a number that it is getting divided by - R

Tags: r

I am looking at a specific use case where I would like to split a number into parts by a number that it is getting divided by
For example : 42/8 = 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 2 or 68/8 = 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do...

```
a <- 42
b <- 8

paste(c(rep(b, a %/% b), a %% b), collapse = ",")

[1] "8,8,8,8,8,2"
```

Or don't use the `paste()` if you just want a vector of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```r
`%div%` <- function(x, y){
  
  if(!x > y) stop("LHS must be greater than RHS")
  
  wholes <- x/y
  remainder <- x %% y
  
  out <- c(rep(y, wholes), remainder[remainder > 0])
  return(out)
}

42 %div% 8
#> [1] 8 8 8 8 8 2

52 %div% 8
#> [1] 8 8 8 8 8 8 4

0.75 %div% 0.25
#> [1] 0.25 0.25 0.25

8 %div% 52
#> Error in 8 %div% 52: LHS must be greater than RHS
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>